# Different email delivery times for mailboxes in the same domain

Tags: email, smtp, email-spam

Just a few moments ago, I sended two mail right after each other to two different mail accounts on the same domain. However if the first one that is send takes about a hour before it arrives and the second one that has been send arrives immediately.

Does anyone have a explanation for what is happening?

With kind regart, 
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible explanations. The most likely is [greylisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) (an anti-spam procedure) with and without hitting whitelist.

- fast delivery hit greylisting whitelist (no delay)
- slow delivery received normal treatment, first delivery attempt received "try later" reply

Greylisting *temporary* whitelist is based on  the following triple:

- sender email address
- IP address of sending host
- recipient address.